# Is it possible to append new values to existing eVar values in SiteCatalyst/Adobe Analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

Is there a way to append new values to existing eVar values instead of overwritten the old one? I believe I saw it somewhere but couldn't find it anymore.

Use case is within one visit, when a user see button1, set eVar1 = 'button1', then when the user see button2, I'd like eVar1 reports 'button1,button2'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Closest I can think of is maybe you mean setting the `eVar` to linear attribution in the interface config. This won't *append* new values to a previous value, but it will *add* a new row with the new value to the report, for the duration of its scope (when it is set to expire).

Alternatively, you may be thinking of the `crossVisitParticipation` plugin, which uses a cookie to append new values to previous values.

**Example:**

```
// first call: eVar1="foo"
s.eVar1=s.crossVisitParticipation('foo','v1','365','10','^','',0);

// visitor comes back another day

// second call: eVar1="foo^bar"
s.eVar1=s.crossVisitParticipation('bar','v1','365','10','^','',0);
```

But note that this doesn't really *append* new values to the existing `eVar`; you're still technically overwriting it with a new value.

Comment: Thanks! What I am looking for is something like crossVisitParticipation but within same visit. Use case is within one visit, when a user see button1, set eVar1 = 'button1', then when the user see button2, I'd like eVar1 reports 'button1,button2'. Do you think that is achievable? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can set how long you want the CVP cookie to last, or use your own cookie method to append values in a visit, but either way, the reports will show an entry for both 'button1' and 'button1,button2'.

Comment: If you want only the individual items in a report but to show the total each item was set with an event, use a listVar and set it to expire with that event. The report would show 'button1'=2, 'button2'=1.

Comment: @Lei `crossVisitParticipation` lets you specify expiration by number of days, and lowest you can do is 1 day.  AFAIK there are no other official Adobe plugins that work like this except for session scope. You could alter the plugin or roll your own that is session scoped. Or you could toss a few bucks my way and I could do it for you ;)

Comment: @CrayonViolent Thanks! Do you think getPreviousValue plugin can help me achieve this goal? Use the plugin to get previous value and then append a new value. The lowest expiration of CVP is 1 day, which may still be too long since I want the value expired at the end of the session.

Answer (score 0):

A `listVar` does actually work like that, but I'm not sure if it's really what you want. The way it works is fairly complex compared to the options Crayon Violent mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Nils. listVar may not work in my case since I need to add different values to same eVar via multiple calls within a visit.

Comment: That's how it works, but it depends on what you want reports to show.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using a path / fallout report in this case which would give you something like this:

Of those visitors who saw button 1 during the visit --> what percentage also went on to see button 2?

Or, If you're simply trying to get a count, you could consider using a list prop that will give you the number of times button 1 was found vs button1,button2.

You could also persist this value over multiple visits by using a cookie.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options what I can think here

- listvar
- use of VISTA rule